# Setup authentication feature between servers Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt

I am working in a project where we have 3 servers:

1. **Frontend** Server running in **Reactjs/redux.**
2. **Backend** application server where project business logic is setup(**DRF**). This doesn't have authorization mechanism.
3. **User management** server where user login/registration(**DRF**).

Currently in this project registration with session and login is implemented but the user session is maintained only User management server.

Authorization system workflow should be as below:

1. A request is made from Frontend server to Backend.
2. Allow only logged in user to get the result.

User Backend server is the one managing user database and session. How can we check in Backend Server if user is logged in through User Management Server and return result back to Frontend Server based on if user is logged in/not.

Token authentication is preferred. I searched for JWT, but the implementation is detailed for single server projects.

Please let me if there is a solution/alternative for the above scenario.

Thanks in advance.